# Let $G$ be a simple planar graph in which every vertex has the same degree $k$. Prove that $k \leq 5$

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a simple planar graph in which every vertex has the same degree $k$. Prove that $k \leq 5$. This is a problem I was given by my professor, but I am struggling to see why it would be true, let alone prove it. It seems to me that any simple graph regular on degree $5$ would have a subgraph of $K_5$, which is not planar. Therefore, the graph itself could not be planar. Any direction on how to disprove my supposed counterexample and start this proof would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Consider the icosahedron.

Comment: That comment handles the "counterexample". For the proof, one way is to show that in every planar graph, six plus the number of edges is at most three times the number of vertices, whereas if every vertex has degree at least six then the number of edges is at least three times the number of vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to Euler's formula we know that edges <= 3n-6 in a planar graph. In your graph which is a regular graph the number of edges = kn/2.
Now compare 3n-6 to kn/2. k < 6 - 12/n which tends to 6 as n tends to infinity. So k < 6.

Comment: Pretty much as I wrote in my comment.